# Dynamic Dropdown Menus If-Else

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am currently making a pair of dropdown menus. The options of the second one dependent on the choice of the user on the first dropdown.

Currently my code doesn't work and does not go into the if else function

```
$city="";
$formcontent =<<<EOT

            <select name="City" id="City">
            <option value="0">Make a Selection</option>
            <option value="City1" $city="City1">City1</option>
            <option value="City2" $city="City2">City2</option>
            </select><br></br>

            <select name="Street" id="Street">
            <option value="0">Make a Selection</option>
EOT;

                    if($city=="City1"){ 

$formcontent. = <<<EOT
                <option value="City1Street1">City1 Street1</option>
                <option value="City1Street2">City1 Street2</option>
EOT;
}
```

Comment: It's right here: http://codepad.org/b4FulPsH To concatenate to a variable, it's `$var .=`, not `$var. =`. Fixed: http://codepad.org/n53YLgV5

Comment: I would prefer ajax for giving list of street based on selected city. You need to just apply onchange event to city dropdown and based on passed value, need to set only innerhtml to street dropdown.

Comment: Where is your if/else function? Is it Javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

you have error near.

```
if($city=="City1"){ 

$formcontent. = <<<EOT ...
```

it should

```
if($city=="City1"){ 

$formcontent .= <<<EOT ..
```

Comment: It still does not go into the if statement. If I select city1, nothing is appended to the choices for street.

Comment: if you want to change the street drop down selection dependent on the city then you need to use javascript / jquery for that.

Comment: you can use $(function(){
$('#city').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();

  if(val =='city1'){
    $('#street').html('<option>street1</option><option>street2</option>');
  }else if(val =='city2'){
    $('#street').html('<option>street3</option><option>street4</option>');
}

});
});